Ubuntu 24.04 power management disabling usb mouse
I am running ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7559 laptop with a logitech m510 usb mouse.  Occasionally on battery, the mouse stops working although the built-in touchpad continues to work.  If I plug in the power cord, the mouse immediately functions again. So I suspect power management is at work.
While there are other instances of this problem on the forums, most are for versions of ubuntu that are out of date.  The services referred to in those posts don't even seem to be installed or running under 24.04.  They mention things like laptop-mode-tools, powernap, or laptop-mode that don't seem to exist (or aren't installed).
So, in short, what application/service/what-have-you is in charge of power management these days, and how do I stop it from disabling the usb mouse?
Not sure what to post for diagnostics - happy to add upon request.
System info:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-06-24 10:01:46

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              Dell Inc. Inspiron 7559
- **Memory:**                                      16.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ × 8
- **Graphics:**                                    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
- **Graphics 1:**                                  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.0 TB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            1.3.1
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               46
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.8.0-35-generic

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b8a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

lsusb -v for device 002
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 [unknown]
  bDeviceSubClass         0 [unknown]
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc52b Unifying Receiver
  bcdDevice           12.10
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Receiver
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0054
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
   Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
          Report Descriptors:
            ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
   Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     148
          Report Descriptors:
            ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               2
   Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 [unknown]
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      93
          Report Descriptors:
            ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               2


It is not actually the mouse that is being turned off it is the power to the USB port. Look at your power settings and see if there is something there you can edit.

I did - but there is not.  The power settings  menu from settings shows several items like 'dim screen' or 'automatic power saver'.  I've turned them all off but to no effect.
If there are text files of power settings to edit, I'm not sure what they are.

You may also want to see if the hardware has any power settings in the BIOS.
